# Extract info from binary file without layout in C#

Tags: c#, parsing, binary, extract

How can I extract information from a binary file that I don't have the layout where the bytes are? Is this even possible?

Let me explain a little:

I want to export data in a lot of Geo Format's like Destinator, TomTom, Polnav. I have samples  of each one, but the companies don't give the layout.

Thanks in advance.

**QUICK UPDATE:** If you guys know some reverse-engineering tool, please, share.

Comment: You need to reverse-engineer the file.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, unless you know the file format it is going to be very difficult (if not impossible) to figure this out.  There is no way to know ahead of time what the various byte layouts might be.  I'd suggest trying to find some documentation on the various formats.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to [Reverse Engineer the File](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Reverse_Engineering/File_Formats).  This can be done with a lot of patience, a good hex editor, and some clever work.  However, it typically requires having a way to save data into the file formats repeatedly to try to figure out the byte alignments yourself.

Expect this to be a huge undertaking.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the layout, the best you can do is try to reverse engineer (as in "guess") what's where.